# Problemas con detección de imagen

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, integer

Hola este código lo saqué de un libro para aprender a utilizar la librería de openCv pero mi código no funciona correctamente en la parte de

```
frame_roi = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

el error que marca es el siguiente:

> ```
> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
> ```

El código es:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

face_mask = cv2.imread('mask_hannibal.png')

h_mask, w_mask = face_mask.shape[:2]

if face_cascade.empty():

    raise IOError('Unable to load the face cascade classifier xml file')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

scaling_factor = 0.5

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face_rects = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 2)

    for (x,y,w,h) in face_rects:

        if h > 0 and w > 0:

            h, w = int(1.4*h), int(1.0*w)
            y -= 0.1*h

            frame_roi = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            face_mask_small = cv2.resize(face_mask, (w, h),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

            gray_mask = cv2.cvtColor(face_mask_small, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ret, mask = cv2.threshold(gray_mask, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

            mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

            masked_face = cv2.bitwise_and(face_mask_small, face_mask_small, mask=mask)
            masked_frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame_roi, frame_roi, mask=mask_inv)

            frame[y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv2.add(masked_face, masked_frame)

    cv2.imshow('Face Detector', frame)
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break
cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que intentas usar floats como índices en un rebanado de un array NumPy, es muy simple de reproducir:

> ```
> >>> import numpy as np
> >>> a = np.array([])
> >>> a[:1.0]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
> ```

Durante un tiempo NumPy permitió usar floats como índices, pero en versiones actuales de NumPy genera la excepción mostrada, siendo congruente con el indizado de Python.

El problema concreto en tu caso es que la línea:

```
y -= 0.1*h
```

hace que `y` sea un floats, por lo que al intentar el rebanado en:

```
frame_roi = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

salta la excepción. La solución en estos casos es convertir el índice a entero antes de intentar usarlo para indizar. Puedes truncarlo con `int()` o `numpy.trunc`, redondearlo mediante `round()` o `numpy.rint` al entero más cercano, aplicar las funciones suelo / `math.floor`/`numpy.floor` o techo (`math.ceil`/`numpy.ceil`), etc, dependiendo de que busques en cada caso, por ejemplo:

```
 y = int(y - 0.1 * h)
```

Permitir el indizado con floats tiene algunos problemas de interpretación y legibilidad, ¿`array[1.5]` que debería obtener el elemento con índice 1 o el que tiene índice 2?¿Y 1.500001 ó 1.9999999? Según el propio zen de Python, "explícito mejor que implícito", si explícitamente realizamos la conversión todo queda más claro y no hay lugar a interpretaciones.